# Customizing the Preview Expression of a Form View using Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table

In Attribute Table, there is a form view instead of the table view and the label of listing on the left side can be customized using preview expression. So the user will notice a friendly and meaningful listing. I can customize it manually but I'm creating an automation plugin to load and configure from my datasets.

I observed, it gets stored as `<previewExpression>` of the layer in the `.qgs` file. However I don't see any related methods in `QgsVectorLayer` python class.

How can I customize the preview expression in Python?

[image: Preview Expression]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [setDisplayExpression()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a68edb8be953bb36e34b1f878d6d62402) method from the [QgsVectorLayer()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) class.

This method only requires a string (remember to escape the `'` or the `"` symbols, otherwise it won't work):

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()

expression=' \'your expression\' '
layer.setDisplayExpression(expression)
```

Using an example and assuming you want to set the values of the `"numbers"` field as a preview expression:

[image]

you may use this code:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()

expression=' \"numbers\" '
layer.setDisplayExpression(expression)
```

and you will have this result:

[image]

Comment: Hey, that time I really looking for an answer. After a week, I just realize you already answered. I just tested it and you are right. Now I don't have to manually set it every time my script create a new layer... I wonder why I overlook the `setDisplayExpression` in the `dir(QgsVectorLayer)`. Great, thanks.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN You're welcome. P.S. The overlooking of some crucial method when browsing a class is a common issue for me too! =)